# Pegar string de um textarea e popular um objeto

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma API,plugin, algo do tipo, e é claro alguma ideia de como eu posso pegar um texto pré formatado, como esse:

```
Cod Nome    Celuler     Telefone    Tel_trabalho
123 Bruno   986159946   27054578    23345689
124 Carlos  986159947   27054579    23345690
125 Rafael  986159948   27054580    23345691
126 Vinicio 986159949   27054581    23345692
127 Sandro  986159950   27054582    23345693
128 Everaldo    986159951   27054583    23345694
129 Vanessa 986159952   27054584    23345695
130 João    986159953   27054585    23345696
```

E popular um objeto inserindo cada linha como parte dos seus atributos.

Comment: Existe um padrao de separação entre os itens?

Comment: @DiegoF cada coluna é separada por \t(tab);

Comment: E as linhas por quebras de linhas normais(\n)?

Comment: @DiegoF sim, são separadas por \n.

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvo isso fazendo minha própria **biblioteca** baseada em anotações de classe. É muito simples de fazer!

A idéia é *declarar* os diferentes layouts de arquivos TXT como classes Java, e depois usar um parser genérico que, a partir de um dado layout (uma classe Java), interprete o um arquivo texto, resultando uma instância daquela mesma classe ou uma lista de instâncias.

Algo assim:

```
@Layout(separator = LayoutSeparator.TAB)
class LayoutPessoa {

    @LayoutField(position = 0)
    Integer codigo;
    @LayoutField(position = 1)
    String nome;
    @LayoutField(position = 2)
    String celular;
    @LayoutField(position = 3)
    String telefone;
    @LayoutField(position = 4)
    String telefoneTrabalho
}

class Main {

    public void static main(String[] args) {

        LayoutParser parser = new LayoutParser(LayoutPessoa.class);

        List<LayoutPessoa> pessoas = parser.parse(conteutoArquivoTxt);

        for(LayoutPessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
            System.out.println(pessoa.nome);
        }
    }
}
```

A anotação *@Layout* ali é só ilustrativa, pra demonstrar que o parser poderia saber ler diferentes separadores além de tab (como vírgula e ponto-e-vírgula), caso você precisasse.

Você também pode ter especializações da anotação *@LayoutField* para ler números ou datas formatadas, e informar o formato em propriedades específicas destas outras anotações.

No caso, você teria algo do tipo:

- *@DateLayoutField(position = 5, format = dd/MM/yyyy)*
- *@NumerLayoutField(position = 6, format = #0.00)*.

Em havendo necessidade, você pode reutilizar quase todo o código para fazer a **operação inversa** usando a mesma declaração de layout, ou seja, pode usar a mesma declaração de layout tanto para ler a **partir de arquivo texto para objetos** quanto para ler **a partir de objetos para arquivo texto**.

**Em suma**, para implementar isso você vai precisar apenas:

- Saber ler linhas de um arquivo texto;
- Saber declarar e ler anotações de uma classe;
- Saber instanciar classes via reflection.

Uma vez que você tenha as linhas dos arquivos representadas em estruturas de dados, fica muito fácil fazer o que quiser com isso em Java, como por exemplo mapear para banco de dados via JPA, serializar para enviar pela rede, etc.

É claro que estou considerando que você tem que ler mais de um layout, e eventualmente está sempre adicionando a capacidade de leitura de novos layouts no projeto. Se você só tem um tipo de arquivo texto pra ler, então não vale a pena.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta! Atualmente utilizo essa solução, porém preciso eliminar a leitura de um arquivo txt ou de qualquer outro. Preciso que os valores venham direto de um textarea.

Comment: sua biblioteca está disponível em algum lugar?

Comment: @BrunoTinelli Ué, qual a diferença entre fazer parser do texto vindo de um arquivo ou vindo de um componente TextArea ou qualquer outra fonte?? O meu código não está disponível, os projetos onde implementei esta solução eram todos proprietários. Todavia se você tiver dúvidas específicas é só perguntar.

Comment: Eu utilizo uma solução parecida como essa, porém não foi eu que implementei. Estou pesquisando mais sobre Reflection e Annotations para implementar uma solução parecida, porém sem arquivos.